# How to solve FCM notification nor working after device is restarted and apps is cleared?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want my android apps to keep receiving notification (FCM) even the device is restarted.

Now, my apps is have to open apps first so notification will appear.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you updating fcm token on refreshing or only one time?

Comment: just once, when registering device.

Comment: No, you must register when a change of token occures. implement the fcm Token service and on token refresh () you must update the token to cloud. Thnks

Comment: is that will solve my problem?
my problem is just not receiving notification when device is restarted. but when that apps was opened, notification will appear.

Comment: Just log that fcm token and compare , you can see the difference

Answer (score 2):

Please refer :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

You can keep `data` payload instead of `notification` payload in you Message from server. This will call `onMessageReceived` irrespective of your application is in foreground or background.

Comment: my apps have been work both in foreground or background. but when device is restarted, need to open apps first in order to notification can be received. how to solve it friend?

Comment: Make sure you follow the procedure mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). I just checked on my device and its working. I followed the procedure as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In `MyFireBaseInstanceIDService`class upload tokento your server from  `onTokenRefresh` method i.e.

```
public class MyFireBaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private SessionManager session;

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Logger.e("FCM Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        if (session.getDataByKey(SessionManager.IS_LOGIN, false)) {
            sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     * <p>
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("userid", session.getUserId());
        params.put("device_id", token);
        params.put("device_type", "A");
        params.put("encrypted_data", Utils.encode(session.getUserId()));

        Retrofit.getInstance("user/updatedevice", params)
                .enqueue(new Retrofit() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(int statusCode, JSONObject jResponse) {
                        Logger.e("Refresh Token updated to server.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailed(int statusCode, String message) {
                        Logger.e("Failed to updated Refresh Token to server.");
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: is that will solve my problem? my problem is, notification not received when i clear running apps on device. but after i clear and reopen that apps, notification will received.